# Swift writing data into Firebase Error Expected Declaration

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just started learning Swift and I have an issue with writing into my Real Time Database. I followed the Firebase docs but still have this problem.

Here is my View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }
        var ref: DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference()

        self.ref.child("Produkt/Kappe/Laden").setValue("Netto") //this is where I am getting the error: "Expected declaration"
}
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Vars can be declared outside of functions but within the class. When you do that it's called a 'class var' because it's available to all functions throughout your class. This would be opposed to a local var which is a var defined within a function and only available within that function. You should reference class vars with `self.`, like you are `self.ref` to make it clear it's a class var. When you want to work with it, reading it's value for example, that would generally be done inside a function as in @Reed answer `self.ref.child("Pr...` so move that code within a function. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this inside viewdidload or any function
because you cannot perform these actions outside function scope

Try this

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            self.ref.child("Produkt/Kappe/Laden").setValue("Netto")

}
    var ref: DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference()


}
```

you cannot do this outside any function.